# JEditorPane <ol></ol> do space instance of put poins

Tags: java, html, swing, web, jeditorpane

I have my JEditor pane set up with my page intro all works fine but the code  do that all the text come down some lines like 
.
Who can i fix it ?

I have this HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#eee"/>
    <meta name="color:Content Background" content="#fff"/>
    <meta name="color:Heading text" content="{TitleColor}"/>
    <meta name="color:Text" content="#000"/>
    <meta name="color:Links Colors" content="#aaaaff"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        #title {
            color: {color:Heading text};
        }
        #content{
            background-color: {color:Content Background};
            color: {color:Text};
        }
        A{
            color: {color:Links Colors};
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="{color:Background}">
<ol><h1 id="title">{Title}</h1></ol>
    <div id="content">
        <br>
        <ol>
            {block:Posts}
                {block:Text}
                    {block:Title}
                        <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    {/block:Title}
                    {Body}
                {/block:Text}
            {/block:Posts}
        </ol>
    </div>
```

In web its work but in the JEditPane the tag `<ol> </ol>` do that's all my text go down like `<br>` tag.

Comment: Can you provide the generated HTML you have and what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

JEditorPane only supports HTML3.2. I'm not sure what the `{block:???}` tags are but I would guess JEditorPane does not recognize them.

As far as I know you need to use `<li>` tags when using an ordered list.

Comment: {block:} .... are from tumblr.com thads only say the theme where to put the text post audio post bla bla...